# How can I make the "add task" button not accepting empty strings?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

the following code has an error where the "add task" button will add an empty input into the listbox by creating spaces between 2 tasks.  Is there a way by coding this where it can't happen?  I want the list in the listbox to be sequential where each task appears one after another.  I don't understand why this happens.  Is it a part of python? Thanks again.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("350x450")
    root.title("basic window")
    root.config(background="azure")
    app = Application (root)
    root.mainloop()


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="yellow", bd=2, relief=tk.RIDGE)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

        #widget layout

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, height="15")
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=5)

        self.entry=tk.Entry(self, width=19)
        self.entry.grid(row=1, stick="w", padx=5)

        self.button1=tk.Button(self, text="add task", command=self.update)
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w", padx=5)

        self.label=tk.Label(self, text="stats", bg="yellow")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="n")

        #programing

    def update(self):

        self.listbox.insert("end", self.entry.get())
        self.entry.delete(0, "end")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

in `update(self)`, you need to test if `self.entry.get()` contains an empty string; if it does, skip the update.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="yellow", bd=2, relief=tk.RIDGE)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

        #widget layout

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, height="15")
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=5)

        self.entry=tk.Entry(self, width=19)
        self.entry.grid(row=1, stick="w", padx=5)

        self.button1=tk.Button(self, text="add task", command=self.update)
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w", padx=5)

        self.label=tk.Label(self, text="stats", bg="yellow")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="n")

        #programing

    def update(self):
        if self.entry.get() != '':
            self.listbox.insert("end", self.entry.get())
            self.entry.delete(0, "end")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("350x450")
    root.title("basic window")
    root.config(background="azure")
    app = Application (root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Reblochon, the code works.  Thanks very much.  I guess this will need to be done every time there is a user input.

Comment: yes; as it stands, the input string is tested every time the button is pressed. If you need more input fields, and want to prevent empty strings from being entered, you can use the same technique in their respective callback methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
def update(self):
        if not self.entry.get()== "": #.get gets the value thgat the entry contains
            self.listbox.insert("end", self.entry.get())
            self.entry.delete(0, "end")
```

Also on a side note i would suggest using better names for example instead of `self.entry` use something `self.intput_txt`, when i make object i tend to use `_txt` or `_lbl` ectra as it makes it easier to see at a glance what type of object it is

Comment: Hi, I tried to just keep it simple for now.  with the under score it makes me think more.  hahaha I am a new programmer.

Comment: np anything else you dont get dont hesitate to post